# Question about understanding of C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
rackList.ForEach((rackId) =>
{
    var query = this.inventoryClient.CreateQuery<RackEntity>().Where(r => r.Id == rackId).Include(r => r.Type).Include(r => r.MapiVlan);
```

This is part of the code I have. The question is simple, how do I understand this part of the code? What will be the equivalent form in SQL query? What is the use of Include()?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Also please specify in your tags what database platform you are using and what style of LINQ (I am assuming Entity Framework? EF Core perhaps?)?

Comment: For EF (Entity Framework) Include simply means that depend data is loaded as well. Referring to your code: For Rackentity the Class `Type` is also loaded from the database

Comment: @Willie The code is looking at each rack in the racklist, but what is this CreateQuery here doing? My current understanding is, it's creating a list of RackEntity with the same rackID found from the rack list. Is it correct?

Comment: @Willie Also what is the purpose of loading the Type class? I don't quite understand your explanation, can you please provide an example? or equivalent form in sql?

Comment: @KevinYuan See the proposed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example SQL statement might be

```
Select r.name, r.address, t.category, m.address from RackEntity r
Where r.Id = Id
Inner Join [Type] t on t.RackEntityId = r.Id
Inner Join MapiVLan m on m.RackEntityId = r.Id
```

except that instead of individual columns, you're returning all of them from each of the three tables (and then loading the data into objects.)

Comment: I'm confused. Where does that lower case r come from?

Comment: The lower case "r" is an alias for the table name.  That's what "...from RackEntity r ..." means (the r after "RackEntity" is the alias.)  Using that syntax, instead of having to write RackEntity.Id or RackEntity.Address, you can shorted it to r.id or r.address.